# Postgres Query to replace the last occurence of input data

Tags: sql, postgresql, regexp-replace

**Input:**

| field |
| --- |
| ABC_PKG_T |
| ABC_T_PKG |
| ABC_PKG_T2 |
| abc_base_t |

**Output:**

| field |
| --- |
| ABC_PKG |
| ABC_T_PKG |
| ABC_PKG_T2 |
| abc_base |

I have used the following logic:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(field), '(.*)\_T|_t', '\1' )
```

and it's working fine to fetch most of the output value except for the third output value I am getting "*ABC_PKG2*".

Can you please suggest any other logic so that I will get the result as ABC_PKG_T2 correctly?

Comment: Your title says: "*Postgres Query to find out the last occurence and replace it*". Can you define last occurrence with respect to what?

Comment: Hi,Last occurence in the example is _T or _t

Comment: End of line symbol is `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor the expression at the end of the string using `$`:

```
regexp_replace(the_column, '_t\s*$', '', 'i')
```

The `\s*` will also remove any trailing white space that follow the `_t` and the `'i'` makes this case insensitive so it will remove `_T` as well as `_t`

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name.Can you also help how to write the same query in Teradata as well.